# Django Registration Redux: Add extended User Profile error

Tags: django, django-registration

I am trying to add some extended fields to the user. So I have added a UserProfile class as you would do.

I also created a UserProfile form:

```
class UserProfileForm(RegistrationFormUniqueEmail):

first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)

class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ['gender', 'phone']
```

And then set up a custom RegistrationView:

```
from registration.backends.default.views import RegistrationView

from forms import UserProfileForm

class UserRegistrationView(RegistrationView):

   form_class = UserProfileForm

   def register(self, request, form_class):
       new_user = super(UserRegistrationView, self).register(request, form_class)
       new_user.first_name = form_class.cleaned_data['first_name']
       new_user.last_name = form_class.cleaned_data['last_name']
       new_user.save()
       user_profile = new_user.get_profile()
       user_profile.gender = form_class.cleaned_data['gender']
       user_profile.phone = form_class.cleaned_data['phone']
       user_profile.save()
       return user_profile
```

I am adding the custom view to my app's routes:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from userprofile import regbackend

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   url(r'^accounts/register/$',    regbackend.UserRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
   url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),

]
```

However, when I try and register a new user I get the following error:
'AttributeError at /accounts/register/ 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'set_password'

Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: The `UserProfileForm` should have the opposite behavior. Your user model should be the form's Meta model (not the profile model) and both gender and phone should be explicitly declared (like you currently do with first_name and last_name). I believe this will work

Comment: You are right, that did the trick! Thank you!